# Why menu in ActionBar in Android can get focus with view.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0) in which actionBarHeight is not for sure?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, padding

I have view like follow:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+                             Here is ActionBar                                     +
+                                                       Menu1     Menu2    Menu3    +
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Here is A View such as ListView wrapped by LinearLayout                        |
|   Content1                                                                        |
|   Content2                                                                        |
|   Content3                                                                        |
|   Content4                                                                        |
|   Content5                                                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my layout file:
main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/content_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/file_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/selector_list_item"
    />
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "LOG: " + ListViewActivity.class.getName();

    private FileNode mCurrentNode;

    private ListView mDetailsView;

    private List<FileNode> mNodeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.file_details);

        mCurrentNode = new FileNode(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_root);
        linearLayout.setPadding(0, 88, 0, 0);     // 88 is just the exactly value make the action bar get focued(but platform depended), 87 is not ok
        mDetailsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.file_item);

        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemList.add("item1");
        itemList.add("item2");
        itemList.add("item3");
        itemList.add("item4");
        itemList.add("item5");
        itemList.add("item6");
        itemList.add("item7");
        itemList.add("item8");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_item, itemList);

        mDetailsView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null) return;

        actionBar.show();
    }

    private void loadFile() {
        mNodeList = new ArrayList<FileNode>();
        if (mCurrentNode == null) return;

        File[] files = mCurrentNode.getFile().listFiles();
        if (files == null) return;

        for (File f : files) {
            mNodeList.add(new FileNode(f));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_normal, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:
At the beginning, I can not get the `Menu` in `ActionBar` focused with press `up` key in remote control. Then I add some code like follow:

```
mView = (LinearLayout)findViewLayout(R.id.view_root);
int actionBarHeight = 0;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

mView.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);
```

Then, the `Menu` can get focused.

The curcial code is `mView.setPadding(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);`, I have tried to assign some other value to `actionBarHeight`, this value is not dependent for just now, if `actionBarHeight` makes you see the first item(do not need to see all, just a little is enough), the `ActionBar` will get foucsed.

Comment: it is the horizontalscrollview in my situation

Comment: Could we see your layout? How do you load the ActionBar?

Comment: @miav Because my layout is very complicated at beginning, so just now I simplify the layout file, it takes me some time.

Comment: @miav sorry, I do much more experiments, then I find more problem. The question I asked is not so accurate. I update all the problem again.

Comment: Are you inheriting from a NoActionBar theme and then setting the actionBar at runtime? Do you think the main layout overlaps your ActionBar? Post your ActionBar code so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @miav I have already add almost all my code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch `android:windowActionBarOverlay` from `true` to `false` (or just remove it, `false` should be the default).

Comment: sorry, I forget last night. But today I find that this does not work in another situation, so I need to find the reason.

Comment: @roger that probably is another question. `android:windowActionBarOverlay` is what makes the toolbar and the content overlap.